# Tcl hang in proc return

Tags: tcl, eval, freeze, proc

I write 2 script to do somting like this:

**#script1, to dump info:**

```
proc script1 {} {
  puts $file "set a 123"
  puts $file "set b 456"
  .....
}
```

(The file size I dump is 8GB)

**#And use script2 to source it and do data category:**

```
while { [get $file_wrtie_out_by_script1 line] != -1 } {
  eval $line
}
close $file_wrtie_out_by_script1
Do the job....
return
```

In this case, the script is hang in return, how to solve the issue... stuck 3+ days, thnaks

Update:

Thanks for Colin, now I use source instead of eval, but even remove the "Do the job...", just keep return, still hang

Comment: In script2 why do you read and `eval` the file line-by-line?  Why not just do `source $file_from_script1` ?

Comment: Do you run script2 *after* script1 finishes or *concurrently* ?

Comment: Hi, I use eval just due to the file is too big to source, (file size 13GB), when use source, it show tcl_setobjlength: negative length requested

Comment: I run script2 after script1 finish

Comment: I think an up-to-date Tcl build should be able to handle `source`ing that size of file.  What Tcl version are you using?

Comment: Hi Colin, I use 8.6.4

Comment: ok, 8.6.4 is not too old, so I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: A simpler solution might be just to break your data up into a series of files, so each one is a size that can be `source`d, then script2 can just `source` them one after another.

Comment: Alternatively a more scalable approach could be to use `sqlite3` which usually comes bundled with Tcl8.6.  Script1 would write a database table containing your name/value pairs, then script2 would read this and set the corresponding variables.  See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/SQLite for more info.

Comment: Hi Colin, I follow the suggestion to split into 10 files, and use foreach to source it, and then "return".  The script still stuck at return.

Comment: I assume the `return` is because you are `source`ing these files in a proc.  If so, there is another problem here - doing all these `set`s inside a proc will just create variable which are local to the proc, so when it returns they will all be lost.  To avoid this you would have to either do the `source`ing at global scope, outside any proc, **or** use `uplevel` around the `source` commands.

Comment: However this whole approach seems rather odd.  What is all this data that you are transferring between script1 and script1?  Why so many individual variables rather than arrays or dicts?  If you give us more background it may be possible to suggest a better approach.

Comment: Hi Colin, very thanks.  Script1 is from other's site. I use Script1's content to do analyze. Because the script1's content will be huge, so I may use SOURCE to read these variable (I think parser script1 will take very long time. So I think source way is better). And Script2 is my site, I source these varaible and then do some jobs (like analyze and cluster these variable)

Comment: `return`ing from a sourced script doesn't lose variable settings.  It just stops the sourcing.  It's unnecessary if it's the last command in the script.    The commands in a sourced script are evaluated at the same namespace as the one that calls the source command.

Answer (score 3):

The `gets` command will return the number of characters in the line that it just read from the file channel.

When all the lines of the file have been read, then `gets` will return -1.

Your problem is that you have a while loop that is never ending.   Your while loop will terminate when `gets` returns 1.  You need to change the condition to -1 for the while loop to terminate.

I agree with the comment from Colin that you should just use `source` instead of `eval` for each line.   Using eval line-by-line will fail if you have a multi-line command (but that might not be the case in your example).

Comment: sorroy for typo, I use -1 rather than 1..

Comment: would you explain detailed? -->Using eval line-by-line will fail if you have a multi-line command

Comment: In file I dump lots of setting command, and use eval to make setting

Comment: If you want a bit-at-a-time `source`, use `info complete` to determine when you have a chunk to feed into `eval`...